# Archive Manager - not cleaning up temporary files

Tags: 2011-sp1, archive-manager-1-sp3

We have Archive Manager 1.00 running on our content delivery servers, which are JBoss/Oracle/Linux.  We've just been sent a "high disk space utilisation" incident, which seems to implicate Archive Manager.

A number of files have been stored in `.../cdeServer1/bin/tmp/ArchiveManager` - 20GB worth over >675,000 files, apparently (!), e.g.

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jboss jboss    19558 May 16  2016 arc4604600835196932209
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jboss jboss    18199 May 16  2016 arc5077129957537477568
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jboss jboss    19333 May 16  2016 arc4841114156653131755
```

The content of the files appears to be deployed, rendered content - HTML and Javascript.  Most of the files are dated 2016, so my gut is they could be removed, but the number and size of them is making me think twice!

I cannot see any mention of this location in the configuration XML files - the closest is in `web.xml` and specifies `/tmp/` (not `cdeServer1/bin/tmp/`) as the upload directory for com.tridion.transport.HTTPSReceiverServlet.

Two simple questions:

1. Can these files be safely deleted?
2. Is there any reason they have not been cleared up automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the files can be safely deleted.

We took the sensible approach and moved the directory to a different location with no obvious ill effects.  The moved directory has now been deleted and the application is still working normally.